# Excel Grouping and Aggregation of Arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a LAMBDA function to generate a new two-column table from two ranges of probability distribution and probability outcomes. The idea is to list all possible outcomes if a random event happens twice and calculate each income's final probability.

To do so I have to multiply each outcome and distribution with all other outcomes and distributions, then group all distribution values based on the unique outcome and calculate the sum of those, finally creating a table that contains only a single row per outcome for the first column and the sum of all combined distributions corresponding with that outcome.

I have tried the below function, but it fails to do so returning `#VALUE!` for each result. I suppose this is because I am not using a range and this function only accepts range for the first and second argument.

```
=LAMBDA(
    distribution, 
    outcome,
    LET(
        p, TOCOL(VALUE(distribution*TRANSPOSE(distribution))),
        q, TOCOL(VALUE(outcome+TRANSPOSE(outcome))),
        t, UNIQUE(q),
        s, SUMIF(q, t, p),
        n, CHOOSE({1,2}, t, s),
        SORT(n, 1, 1)
    )
)
```

I have also tried the following function:

```
=LAMBDA(
    distribution, 
    outcome,
    LET(
        p, TOCOL(VALUE(distribution*TRANSPOSE(distribution))),
        q, TOCOL(VALUE(outcome+TRANSPOSE(outcome))),
        t, UNIQUE(q),
        s, SUMPRODUCT((TRANSPOSE(q)=t)*TRANSPOSE(p)),
        n, CHOOSE({1,2}, t, s),
        SORT(n, 1, 1)
    )
)
```

However, this function returns the SUM of all distributions regardless of the outcome, and therefore no grouping happens.

Please advise on how can I group and aggregate the results of two arrays as described above.

Following is the data and the expected output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **probability** | **outcome** |
| 0.10 | 100 |
| 0.40 | 180 |
| 0.50 | 250 |

inputting this into the named LAMBDA function as `MyFunction(A2:A4, B2:B4)` should produce the following table:

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| 0.01 | 200 |
| 0.08 | 280 |
| 0.10 | 350 |
| 0.16 | 360 |
| 0.25 | 500 |
| 0.40 | 430 |

Comment: Please create a small dataset and expected output.  I will help us understand your needs better.

Comment: you most likely will need to do BYROW() instead of SUMIF.  SUMIFF does not allow the use of arrays, only ranges.

Comment: `t,BYROW(q,LAMBDA(z,SUM(FILTER(p,t=z))),` But without data I cannot test.

Comment: thanks for trying to help Scott. I have tried the BYROW function it doesn't seem to work with `#VALUE!` error. but I will try reading more about it and fix it if I can. I also added a sample data and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=LAMBDA(distribution,outcome,
    LET(
        p, TOCOL(VALUE(distribution*TRANSPOSE(distribution))),
        q, TOCOL(VALUE(outcome+TRANSPOSE(outcome))),
        t,UNIQUE(q),
        s, BYROW(t,LAMBDA(z,SUM(FILTER(p,q=z)))),
        n, CHOOSE({1,2}, s, t),
        SORT(n, 1, 1)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
=LAMBDA(distribution,outcome,
    LET(
        p, TOCOL(VALUE(distribution*TOROW(distribution))),
        q, TOCOL(VALUE(outcome+TOROW(outcome))),
        t, UNIQUE(q),
        s, MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(q)=t),(p)),
        n,HSTACK(s,t),
        SORT(n)
    ))(A2:A4,B2:B4)
```

MMULT could be used as well